# Get next news record in Fluid Template?

Tags: typo3, fluid, typo3-6.2.x

I am creating a custom news template for tx_news which uses a Fluid Template.

I need to get the **uid** of the **next** news record in the loop.

```
<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
    <div id="{newsItem.uid}">
        <a href="#{newsItem.next.uid???}">Go to next</a>
    </div>
</f:for>
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use the extension `vhs`, it provides a ton of useful ViewHelpers - among them the ViewHelper [`v:iterator.next`](https://fluidtypo3.org/viewhelpers/vhs/3.0.0/Iterator/NextViewHelper.html). I've never used it, but from reading the documentation I'd use it like this (using the ViewHelper `v:variable.set` from the same extension for a creating a local variable):

```
{namespace v=FluidTYPO3\Vhs\ViewHelpers}

<f:for each="{news}" as="newsItem" iteration="iterator">
    <div id="{newsItem.uid}">
        <v:variable.set name="nextNews" value="{news -> v:iterator.next(needle: newsItem)}"/>
        <a href="#{nextNews.uid}">Go to next</a>
    </div>
</f:for>
```